# Git deny LFS overwrites

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

It is possible to overwrite a git lfs pointer with an 'ordinary' binary file.

Is there a way to prevent this, other than looking carefully at your commits?

For example a server side policy which denies such overwriting commits?

Comment: Git itself is *unaware of* Git-LFS. Git-LFS swaps the files around *before* Git ever *sees* them. So it's not possible to handle this within Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an uncommon occurrence, and it can happen if a user doesn't have Git LFS properly configured on their client before pushing.

Git LFS 3.0 provides the `git lfs fsck --pointers` option, which is [documented in the manual page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-fsck.1.ronn).  You can run this in your CI, or, if Bitbucket provides `pre-receive` hooks, you can run it there as well.  If you can't use a `pre-receive` hook, then you can't prevent the code from being pushed, but you can of course prevent it from being merged.

I'd recommend upgrading to 3.0.2, since the original 3.0 release had a few bugs in this regard which have since been fixed.

Comment: This is a doable solution for the asked question and I am happy to hear from it. It is the answer to the question